# nwidart/laravel-modules not finding modules on Windows WSL but works fine on OSX

Tags: php, laravel, windows-subsystem-for-linux, laravel-modules

Here's the issues

The environment is a fresh install of Laravel using Sail. The project is using modules and everything works pretty much as advertised for us on OSX. There are several modules created that are working perfectly.

When developers try to set it up on their Windows machine using WSL Ubuntu the modules don't seem to be recognized.

I'm determining this by running the command sail artisan module:list
On OSX it shows all modules and on the Ubuntu install it returns nothing.

The git repo is cloned on the Ubuntu side along with all other commands. artisan make:model works perfectly.

I tried to prove that it could be permissions but all the folders are set to 777 for the user who is using the machine, and that user has root permissions. idk if being in docker means there's something else going on, I'm not aware of anything.

I'm at a loss here for what could be the issue, does anyone have any ideas I could investigate?

Comment: There is a file in the root of the project with the name of `module_status.json`, check the contents. Try also to run `module:enable` Let's see if the modules need to be enabled

Comment: The json file exists, the values are all set to true. I tried the module:enable but it didnt find anything on the windows side.

Answer (score 1):

So heres what I found, the modules directory was using a lowercase m in the project. On OSX it must have figured out the namespace and did some magic so it works. but on WSL it seems a bit stricter.

tldr: Change modules/ to Modules/ and it works perfectly.

Comment: Modules with a capital M is the default value, if you prefer to have modules with a lowercase m you can change the path of modules in the package config